# How to color some edges in different color in Neo4j graph

Tags: php, neo4j

I have neo4j graph which I want to color the new nodes or edges added in different color. For that I used the following code:

```
copy('data/charlize.json', 'data/charlize2.json');
$filename = 'data/diffId.json';
$ligne= file($filename);
$nbTotalLignes=count($ligne);
$tabId = array();
for($i=0;$i<$nbTotalLignes;$i++){
$tabId[$i] =trim($ligne[$i]);
}
$path_to_file = 'data/charlize2.json';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);

for($i=0;$i<$nbTotalLignes;$i++){
$findme   = '"id":"' . $tabId[$i]. '"';
$pos = strpos($file_contents, $findme);
        if (!empty($pos)) {
            $file_contents = str_replace($findme.',"fun_fact":["user"]',       $findme.',"cluster":"0","fun_fact":["user"]',$file_contents);
            $file_contents = str_replace($findme.',"fun_fact":["folder1"]', 
        }
     }
```

With this code I can color the node, but if I add a new edge I can't color it with a different color  (red color).

To be more clear, to color a new node, I add the property: "cluster":"0", but this property didn't work with edges.
Could you please help me to find a solution????.

Comment: Can you please ask clear questions? everytime I see you asking on stackOverflow nobody understands your problem and you don't give enough details

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I explain to you, I have a graph with nodes and Edges. the objective of my application is to secure the data. I have some users each one has access to a specific folder. For example Yannick has access to Folder1 and Julie to Folder2. If Yannick get access to Folder 2 too, I have to see the edge between Yannick and Folder 2 in red color. Please do not hesitate to contact me for further information

Answer (score 0):

In d3 you would have a different stroke or fill function for your relationships, which you can e.g. control from a relationship property.
Not sure what you'd need php for this part.

See this for an JS example: neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/